# The codebook package cannot work due to "knit_asis"

Tags: r

I encounter a issue when I try to use codebook package in Rstudio, it cannot generate a dataframe. When I use the code to force it to generate a dataframe:

```
library(codebook)
cd<-as.data.frame(codebook(dat))
```

It tells me that"Error in as.data.frame.default(codebook(dat)) : cannot coerce class ‘"knit_asis"’ to a data.frame".

I tried to google to see the similar issue and solution, but could not find an answer. It also cannot run package codebookr. When I use package "codebookr", it can generate a list instead of dataframe, but when I click each list, it gives another error like out of bounderies[[i]].

Does someone happen to experience the same issue and have a solution to share? Thanks a lot~~!

It can be generated as value:
[image]

But cannot be forced to be a dataframe:
[image]

Comment: `codebook()` returns a *markdown document* (or something like it). Calling `as.data.frame` on it doesn't make sense. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I am trying to write out a csv format codebook for the dataset: dat in R markdown. Before I used the codebook package, I can just use code: codebook(dat), but now, for this new laptop, it only show the values, i do not know how to export that into a csv format codebook.